# Piece just fell off from under my car

Tags: honda, car

So this piece just fell off from under my car. It's a Honda Civic 2003. I need to drive home, will I explode on the way? It appears to be the shell of something
Thanks in advance!!

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL6dO.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Only if you stop on a pile of dry leaves.  That's a heat shield for a cat, they get hot, and without heat shields, have been known to start fires.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like an exhaust heatshield. You can (probably, can't guarantee) drive home without damage, but it could do damage to leave it off long-term.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It's made me much less worried about driving home! :)

Comment: Right!  probably a cat converter heat shield.

Comment: Given the state of the heat shield and the fact it came off I'd suggest you get the whole exhaust system looked at @Gh90978

Comment: Here's what the catalytic converter might [look like](http://www.proimporttuners.com/images/products/extra_images/513/9943_513___22624.jpg).  What would have here would be like half of the heat shield.

Comment: Until it is repaired or replaced do not park over anything flammable such as grass, leaves or debris. The exhaust can easily get hot enough to start a fire.

Comment: Keep in mind that the cat shield is a two-piece affair. The other half either fell off and was lost or is dangling from your O2 sensor. Might be a good idea to look. If it's gone, yay! If it's dangling from your O2 sensor you should get it off. The electrical connections for the O2 sensor are about 12" from the sensor, sometimes tucked up in the trans tunnel.